# Why couldn't Foaly tell that Artemis had planned more than what he let on under the effect of the Mesmer while he was editing Artemis's memories?

Tags: artemis-fowl, artemis-fowl-the-eternity-code

In *Artemis Fowl and the Eternity Code*, the last chapter - called *Mind Wipe* - has the following line:

> Holly watched Artemis's life being written in green symbols on the screen.

If Foaly and the other fairies could *read his mind like an open book*, they should have made sure that Artemis was not trying to fool them. It seems only logical that Foaly double-check Artemis' memory to make sure that he hadn't planned anything in advance to somehow thwart Foaly's mind wipe.

**Why couldn't Foaly tell that Artemis had planned more than what he let on under the effect of the Mesmer while he was editing Artemis's memories?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Artemis and Butler tricked the *mesmer* by wearing mirrored contact lenses.**

It's part of the plot point for the next book: *The Opal Deception*.

When Artemis "meets" Holly for the "first" time, Artemis recalls finding contact lenses in his eyes, with no memory of ordering them:

> "After my alleged mind wipe, I discovered mirrored contact lenses in my own eyes and in Butler's. Investigation revealed I myself had ordered the lenses, though I had no memory of the fact. I suspect that I ordered them to cheat your *mesmer*."
>
> <sup>Chapter 5: Meet the Neighbours - The Opal Deception</sup>

Holly then confirms that they indeed could have tricked the mesmer by wearing these contact lenses:

> Holly nodded. It made sense. Fairies had the power to mesmerize humans, but eye contact was part of the trick, coupled with a mesmeric voice. Mirrored contact lenses would leave the subject completely in control, while still pretending to be under the *mesmer*.
>
> <sup>Chapter 5: Meet the Neighbours - The Opal Deception</sup>

Because Artemis and Butler were not under the *mesmer*, they were free to lie about any plans they had made. The memory wipe still happened, but their plans to cheat it were not discovered.

To answer why Foaly didn't notice or register any foul play during the mind wipe: **he had already double and triple checked**.

Foaly noticed Artemis had emails ready to be sent back to him with fairy information, storage space on the internet with fairy info, they even found his buried time capsule, filled with his diary and other notes. Foaly installs something on the computer system designed to remove any and all information relating to the People that would stay there for the next six months.

You have to keep in mind that **Artemis Fowl is a genius**. I'm not saying Foaly isn't smart as well, but Artemis managed to escape from the bio bomb in the first book; something no one else had ever done before.

Similarly, no one had ever tricked the *mesmer* and the mind wipe before. So why should Foaly worry after he's already done his due diligence? He sees a mesmerized human, who says they're hiding nothing, so why should he question it?

Comment: This seems like a good answer, but it does not address the main question. I have edited the question to make it more clear. Does that help?

Comment: @InfinityMilestone - I've added some more to the answer that hopefully addresses what you're looking for. I can go on, but it all boils down to Foaly believing the mesmer and trusting Artemis. We can go back and forth all day on why didn't he read the output on the screens (which I agree he should have made quadruple sure) but then if he had caught that then we wouldn't have had the next book.

Comment: And yes the pun is 100% intended